# How do I measure time delay from power ON to console messages

Tags: schematics, voltage-measurement, probe

I am working on [Microzed board (schematic is here)](http://www.zedboard.org/sites/default/files/documentations/MicroZed_RevF_Schematic_140128.pdf). User guide is [here](http://www.zedboard.org/sites/default/files/documentations/MicroZed_HW_UG_v1_4.pdf)

I want to measure time elapsed right from  Power ON to first message that comes on the console.

The message on cosole comes after around 1 second of power ON, and I would like to accuratly measure this time.

I can use a CRO to capture waveforms, but I am not able to figure out what all pins on the board should I probe.

Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than measure the time from a power up, it would be easier to measure the time from a reset, which should be the same thing (except for the time it takes for the power supply to come up, which should be a millisecond or so).

On page 5 of the schematic is a switch, SW2 which is the reset button.  If you tie a line to PS_SRST#, it will go low during a reset (button pressed), and back high when the reset is no longer asserted.  Start timing at this point.

I am assuming the console message comes over the USB UART on the same page.  The TX line (USB_UART_TXD) should start out high.  When the first character is output, it will go low briefly.  That should be the end of your timing.

If the console message comes over some other UART, then use the TX line of that one.

Comment: A reset is a warm reboot; there may be power sequencers that are different in reset versus cold power on.

Comment: @JonWatte Then one could measure from the power up voltage.  The main idea I was trying to point out was how to measure the time the console message appeared, but clocking on the TX lead.

Comment: There are wall plug adapters that take over 1 second to power up. That should be a separate measurement.

Comment: @tcrosley "I am assuming the console message comes over the USB UART on the same page" I did not get this point. What page are you talking about here. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user2799508 By same page, I meant page 5 where the switch SW2 I was discussing is located.  U2, in the bottom right corner of that page, is a USB to UART bridge chip.  If you plug a USB cable into the micro USB jack J2, and connect the other end to a PC, this will create a "virtual COM port" which to software like a terminal program looks like a regular COM port on the machine.  I was assuming that is how you had your conole device connected.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a camcorder set at 60 Hz recording (like 720p/60.) Record yourself powering it on, and point it at the screen.
Then, bring the video into Premiere or whatever and count the number of frames between flipping the switch, and seeing the text. Divide by 60, you get the time from power-on the console output.